# Existence of even permutation which maps first $m$ elements to given $m$ distinct elements

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $m\leq n−2$. Given any $m$ distinct elements $i_1,...,i_m$ from $\{1,...,n\}$, show that there exists a $σ ∈ A_n$ such that $$\sigma(j) = i_j,\ \ \  \forall j\in \{1,...,m\}$$

**What I could do**

I have done almost nothing. I think we have to do induction here. It is easy to show for $n=3$ case, but the inductive step is where I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Suppose you just extend $\sigma$ arbitrarily to $\{1,\dots n\}$ and it turns out to be odd.  Can you turn it into an even permutation that still extends $\sigma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first $m=n-2$. Take any permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ which satisfies $\sigma(j)=i_j$. Then the pair $x,y$ of numbers among $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that does not belong to the initial choice of $n-2$ numbers is mapped to itself. That is, either $\sigma(x)=y, \sigma(y)=x$ or else $\sigma(x)=x,\sigma(y)=y$. Now, if $\sigma$ is already even, stop; else, if $\sigma$ is odd, consider the permutation $\tilde{\sigma}$ that agrees with $\sigma$ on $1\leq j\leq m$ but does the opposite on the pair $\{x,y\}$. This $\tilde{\sigma}$ would then be even.

A simple modification works for $m<n-2$.

Comment: So you are saying, extend $\sigma$ to permutation on $\{1,2,...,n\}$, and multiply it by transposition $(i_{m+1}, i_{m+2})$, if required for evenness?